# jquery live click but not a specific class

Tags: jquery

Sometimes I have the following links

```
<a href="#" class="next_link ">Next</a>

<a href="#" class="next_link no_more">Next</a>
```

But I'm only trying to select the a tags that DOES NOT HAVE no_more inside it. I tried the following but to no avail

```
$('a.next_link.not(.no_more)').live('click', function (){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#dp-products-con").offset().top},'slow');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/Wvggk/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `$('a.next_link:not(.no_more)')`

Note the `:` used before `not`. That is the right way of using it. You were using `.not` which means with a class `not`

Answer (score 0):

This should work too

```
$('a.next_link').not('.no_more').live('click', function (){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#dp-products-con").offset().top},'slow');
});
```

Maybe you you should use the '.on' event  instead of 'live' for better performance.